# How do I get the correct date format string for a given locale without setting that locale program-wide in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, locale

I'm trying to generate dictionaries that include dates which can be asked to be given in specific locales. For example, I might want my function to return this when called with en_US as an argument:

```json
{'date': 'May 12, 2014', ...}
```

And this, when called with hu_HU:

```json
{'date': '2014. május 12.', ...}
```

Now, based on what I've found so far, I should be using `locale.setlocale()` to set the locale I want to use, and `locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_FMT)` to get the appropriate date format. I could call `locale.resetlocale()` after this to go back to the previously used one, but my program uses multiple threads, and I assume the other ones will be affected by this temporary locale change as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the non-standard [babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/) module which offers this and a lot more:

```
>>> import babel.dates
>>> babel.dates.format_datetime(locale='ru_RU')
'12 мая 2014 г., 8:24:08'
>>> babel.dates.format_datetime(locale='de_DE')
'12.05.2014 08:24:14'
>>> babel.dates.format_datetime(locale='en_GB')
'12 May 2014 08:24:16'
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> babel.dates.format_datetime(datetime(2014, 4, 1), locale='en_GB')
'1 Apr 2014 00:00:00'
>>> babel.dates.format_timedelta(datetime.now() - datetime(2014, 4, 1), 
                                 locale='en_GB')
'1 month'
```

Comment: This sounds pretty cool. Do you know if it's completely thread safe? If it is, how does it achieve that?

Comment: I don’t know whether it is thread-safe, but I assume it is—if I had to implement this, I would not use any global state but have read-only lookup tables for locale formattings, which I used whenever I had to format a date.

Comment: Indeed, apparently babel [downloads this file](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/babel/blob/master/scripts/download_import_cldr.py#L16) upon installation of the library, then looks up locale data in that later (or to be more specific, in a mapping it generates from the file during setup).

Answer (score 1):

It might be expensive to do but how about before starting your threads you build a dictionary of `country code: datetime format` entries?

```
for lang in lang_codes:
    locale.setlocale(lang)
    time_format[lang] = locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_FMT)
locale.resetlocale()
```

You can then use the format strings whenever you need the date in a specific format `time.strftime(time_format[lang], t)`. Of course, this doesn't take care of GMT shifts.

The better way would be to find where `locale` gets its mapping from but I don't know that and don't have the time to investigate right now.